# How to make security groups between load balancer and ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I have recently added a ALB for 2 instances in EC2.

I want to make the ALB and EC2 instances to be private so I added the security group for each services.

What I did is that I added the IP Addresses in HTTPS of the EC2 instances in the ALB sg. vice versa in the EC2 sg.

In Route 53. I made a subdomain to link in the DNS name of ALB.

I tried to test it first using sg that is public and it works fine and can access the EC2 application.
But after I tried to set the sg for both the ALB and EC2. 
When I test it, It can't access it.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A security group can allow traffic from a CIDR range of IP addresses, or **from another Security Group**. Thus, you should configure the following **Security Groups**:

- **ALB-SG:** Allow HTTP/S from `0.0.0.0/0` (if you want it open to the world). Associate it with the ALB.
- **App-SG:** Allow HTTP from **ALB-SG**. Associate it with your EC2 instances (or Auto Scaling group Launch Configuration).

The Application Security Group (*App-SG*) is thus permitting incoming traffic from the Load Balancer. Or, more specifically, from any resource that is associated with *ALB-SG*.

**Route 53** should have a `CNAME` record pointing your desired domain name to the **DNS Name of the Load Balancer**.

Comment: For allowing the ALB in App-SG. We will use it's IP ADDRESS? It seems that it is not static? If so, how to get the static IP Address for ALB. Thanks

Comment: Can we use VPC CIDR for the ALB in App-SG?

Comment: Yes. That would restrict access to the Load Balancer to only resources _within_ the VPC.

Comment: Thank you. It works now when I access the domain. The problem is when I access the api routes of the APP it gets 404 Not Found nginx

Comment: The ALB is in HTTPS. Do we need to get a SSL Certificate for nginx in APP?

Comment: No. The ALB can terminate the SSL session, sending HTTP to the application servers.